# How to represent this sentence in description logic?

Tags: semantic-web, description-logic

How to describe this in description logic?

"every human is either male or female"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With propositional calculus, this would be described as:

∀x.H(x) ⊃ (M(x) ∨ F(x)) ∧ (¬(M(x) ∧ F(x)))

where:

```
H(x) = x is human
M(x) = x is male
F(x) = x is female
```

In description logic, it's a little bit different:

```
human ⊆ (male ∪ female) ∩ ¬(male ∩ female)
```

Comment: -1 this & John's answer: Predicate logic is not description logic.  In particular, there is no such thing as unbounded quantification in description logic: quantification is over roles, which is Not The Same Thing.

Answer (score 6):

The answers provided here so far do not use Description Logic syntax (which is variable-free).
Assuming you want the actual Description Logic syntax that is used in scientific papers about Description Logics, check out this:

```
human \sqsubseteq (male \sqcup female) \sqcap \neg (male \sqcap female)
```

Its written in LaTeX, you can use an online LaTeX equation editor, e.g. [this](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) to render this expression.

Comment: +1 for general rightness in the pursuit of rightitude.

Comment: using UTF-8 symbols, `Human ⊑ (Male ⊔ Female) ⊓ ¬(Male ⊓ Female)`. See http://www.paulbrownmagic.com/blog/dl_cheat_sheet.

Answer (score 1):

don't have the ability to comment yet as a newbie but i believe you would want to use an "**exclusive or**"... then again, i guess it depends on your universe of discourse ;)